# Closed Form of Universal formal group law

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-topology

There is Lazard's theorem which states that the universal formal group ring $L$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,x_2,\ldots]$. If we let formally
$\exp(t)=t+\sum\limits_{i>0}b_i t^i$ and $\log(t)$ s.t. $\exp(\log(t))=t$ then we obtain group law $F$ over $\mathbb{Z}[b_1,b_2,\ldots]$ by putting $F(t_1,t_2)=\exp(\log(t_1)+\log(t_2))$.
Then the universal map $L\to \mathbb{Z}[b_1,\ldots]$ identify $L$ with a subring of $\mathbb{Z}[b_1,\ldots]$. This is basic construction behind a proof and after some work we identify $L$ as free polynomial algebra.

I have three questions:

1. Is there are any expression for a universal group law over $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\ldots]$?
2. Is there are any expression for a generators of $L\subset \mathbb{Z}[b_1,\ldots]$ in terms of $b_i$?
3. Is there are explicit and closed expression for a generators of complex cobordism ring $\pi_*(MU)\sim L$?

Comment: For question 1 you have just defined the universal group law $F$. That is the expression you want isn't it? What more do you want? What is the difference between $x_i$ and $b_i$?

Comment: @Somos, abstract fact is that $x_i=\pm d_i b_i$ modulo decomposable elements in $\mathbb{Z}[b_i]$, where $d_i=p$ if $i=p^s-1$ for some prime $p$ and integer $s>0$ and $d_i=1$ in other case. So Lazard's ring $L$ is the proper subring of $\mathbb{Z}[b_i]$ and it is generated by coefficients of $F$, but to write down free-generators $x_i$ is to solve non-trivial combinatorial problem. Put it simply to start with -- the element $p b_{p^2-1}$ might not lying in $L$, but what is a candidate for $x_{p^2-1}$?
May be there is a way to solve question 1 without solving question 2.